# Loop through an api get request with variable URL

Tags: node.js, api, needle.js

I am trying to call CompaniesHouse API and fetch companies registered between November and February. The approach I took is to pick a starting index(a company registered in November) and a stop index(a company registered in February) and loop through to get the companies registered between the start and stop index. Like so:

```
var needle = require("needle");
var startIdx = 11059000;
var stopIdx  = 11211109;
for(idx = startIdx; idx < stopIdx; idx++)
{
    needle('get', "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/"+idx, { 
       username: key,password:"" 
    })
   .then(function(data) {

   })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Call the locksmith!' + err)
  })
}
```

But this doesn't work as gives either a timeout or socket hangup error.

The API is currently in beta and some features are still yet to be implemented.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832718/error-pushing-objects-into-another-object-in-mongodb/48832920#48832920

Comment: @RahulSharma That seems like a db fetch, I don't understand how it relate to this. can you explain pls?

Comment: Just check how to loop for async call, instead of db call you call api.

Comment: Use Promise.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `for` loop runs synchronously and your calls to `needle()` are asynchronous and therefore do not block, you end up attempting to start more than 100,000 network requests at once.  This overwhelms either your local computer or the target server and you start getting socket errors.

For this many requests, you need to run them X at a time so no more than X are in flight at the same time.  To maximize performance, you will have to figure out what value of X you want to use because it will depend upon the target server and how it handles lots of simultaneous requests.  It is generally safe to start with a value of 5 and then increase it from there to test higher values.

If you were processing an array, there are a number of pre-built options to run X requests at once.  The simplest is to use a pre-built concurrency management operation such as Bluebird.  Or you can write your own.  You can see examples of both here: [Make several requests to an API that can only handle 20 request a minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378923/make-several-requests-to-an-api-that-can-only-handle-20-request-a-minute/33379149#33379149)

But, since you are not processing an array, but are just incrementing a number for each successive request, I couldn't find a pre-built option that does that.  So, I wrote a general purpose one where you can fill in the function that will increment your index:

```
// fn gets called on each iteration - must return a promise
// limit is max number of requests to be in flight at once
// cnt is number of times to call fn
// options is optional and can be {continueOnError: true}
// runN returns a promise that resolves with results array.  
// If continueOnError is set, then results array 
// contains error values too (presumed to be instanceof Error so caller can discern
// them from regular values)
function runN(fn, limit, cnt, options = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let inFlightCntr = 0;
        let results = [];
        let cntr = 0;
        let doneCnt = 0;

        function run() {
            while (inFlightCntr < limit && cntr < cnt) {
                let resultIndex = cntr++;
                ++inFlightCntr;
                fn().then(result => {
                    --inFlightCntr;
                    ++doneCnt;
                    results[resultIndex] = result;
                    run();          // run any more that still need to be run
                }).catch(err => {
                    --inFlightCntr;
                    ++doneCnt;
                    if (options.continueOnError) {
                        // assumes error is instanceof Error so caller can tell the
                        // difference between a genuine result and an error
                        results[resultIndex] = err;       
                        run();          // run any more that still need to be run
                    } else {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                });
            }
            if (doneCnt === cnt) {
                resolve(results);
            }
        }
        run();
    });
}
```

Then, you could use this like this:

```
const needle = require("needle");
const startIdx = 11059000;
const stopIdx  = 11211109;
const numConcurrent = 5;
let idxCntr = startIdx;

runN(function() {
    let idx = idxCntr++;
    return needle('get', "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/"+idx, { 
        username: key,password:"" 
    });
}, numConcurrent, stopIdx - startIdx + 1, {continueOnError: true}).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

To minimize memory use, you can use a `.then()` handler on your call to `needle()` and trim down the response to only what you need in the final array:

```
const needle = require("needle");
const startIdx = 11059000;
const stopIdx  = 11211109;
const numConcurrent = 5;
let idxCntr = startIdx;

runN(function() {
    let idx = idxCntr++;
    return needle('get', "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/"+idx, { 
        username: key,password:"" 
    }).then(response => {
        // construct the smallest possible response here and then return it
        // to minimize memory use for your 100,000+ requests
        return response.someProperty;
    });
}, numConcurrent, stopIdx - startIdx + 1, {continueOnError: true}).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to optimize the code ? I'm getting a out-of-memory error.

Comment: @imraj -  What are you getting for all those sites with `needle()`?  Do you need everything that it returns or can you trim it down to keep only a small amount of that data.  You are collecting an array of more than 100,000 of whatever that is.  If it's got a lot of stuff in it, then that uses a lot of memory.  If you show me what you're getting and what you actually need to keep, then I can offer advice on keeping less so it uses less memory.  Alternatively, you could do a 1000 of them, collect the results, process them, then get rid of the data, then do the next 1000.

Comment: @imraj - See what I added to the end of my answer, related to memory use.

Answer (score 0):

```
var needle = require("needle");
var startIdx = 11059000;
var stopIdx  = 11211109;
const promises = [];
for(idx = startIdx; idx < stopIdx; idx++)
{
    promises.push(
        needle('get', "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/"+idx, { 
            username: key,password:"" 
        })
    )
}

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {console.log(results);}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

A simple `Promise.all` implementation can help.

Comment: This doesn't prevent the problem the OP has.  Their issue is that they have too many request in flight at the same time.