# waiting for web worker making http call to finish

Tags: promise, async-await, web-worker

I'm creating multiple web workers making http calls. I have to limit the number of web workers and so I'm trying to wait for some of the workers to finish.

here's an example of what I thought might work using Promises:

```
anArray.map(async contact => {
    await new Promise((res, rej) => {
          const worker = new Worker('./http.worker', { type: 'module' });
          worker.onmessage = () => {
            res();
          };
          worker.postMessage(contact);
    });
});
```

I thought this would wait for each promise to resolve before moving on to the next item... but it's not.

What could I do to make this work? or... I've also thought of building an array of workers and run a recursive loop that checks/waits for one to be available... I'm open to general suggestions for solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map()` is not promise aware.  It does not look at the return value from each iteration to see if it's a promise and then pause the loop.  Instead, it just blindly runs all the iterations one after another.  When you return promises from `.map()` which you are with the `async` callback, that just means that your `.map()` will produce an array of promises and all your loop iterations will be "in-flight" at the same time, not sequenced.

If you want to iterate a loop and pause the loop in each iteration until a promise resolves, then use a regular `for` loop:

```
async function someFunc() {
    for (let contact of anArray) {
        await new Promise((res, rej) => {
              const worker = new Worker('./http.worker', { type: 'module' });
              worker.onmessage = () => {
                res();
              };
              worker.postMessage(contact);
        });
    }
}
```

---

FYI, http calls in Javascript are non-blocking and asynchronous so it's not entirely clear why you're doing them in WebWorkers.  Unless you have CPU-intensive processing of the result, you can do the http requests in the main thread just fine without blocking it.

---

Also FYI, for a number of different options for processing an array, with only N requests in flight at the same time (where you decide what value N is), see these various answers:

`runN(fn, limit, cnt, options)`: [Loop through an API on multiple requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842555/loop-through-an-api-get-request-with-variable-url/48844820#48844820)

`pMap(array, fn, limit)`: [Make several requests to an api that can only handle 20 at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378923/make-several-requests-to-an-api-that-can-only-handle-20-request-a-minute/33379149#33379149)

`rateLimitMap(array, requestsPerSec, maxInFlight, fn)`: [Proper async method for max requests per second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730745/choose-proper-async-method-for-batch-processing-for-max-requests-sec/36736593#36736593)

`mapConcurrent(array, maxConcurrent, fn)`: [Promise.all() consumes all my ram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654265/promise-all-consumes-all-my-ram/46654592#46654592)

There are also features to do this built into the [Bluebird promise library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) and the [Async-promises library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-promises).